# How to make an HTML collapsible button default to expanded?

Tags: html, button, collapsable

I have an HTML page with multiple collapsible buttons.  I'd like one button to be expanded when the page is loaded.  Right now all buttons are collapsed by default.  How do I change the HTML or CSS so that a particular button (Current Week) is expanded and the rest are collapsed?  Here's the relevant code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    Prior_Recordings_HTML5
    </title>
</head>
    <link href="CSS/my_site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<body>
<table class="table_for_collapse">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class=collapsible>Current Week&mdash;November 8, 2020</button>
            <div class=collapsible_content>
                <a href="https://my_site_link_1" target="_blank" class="link3"
                    title="Sunday 11/8/2020">
                    Click here for Sunday, 11/8/2020<br />
                </a>
                <a href="https://my_site_link_2" target="_blank" class="link3"
                    title="Monday 11/9/2020">
                    Click here for 11/9/2020<br />
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class=collapsible>Prior Week 1&mdash;November 1, 2020</button>
            <div class=collapsible_content>
                <a href="https://my_site_link_3" target="_blank" class="link3"
                    title="Sunday 11/1/2020">
                    Click here for Sunday, 11/1/2020<br />
                </a>
                <a href="https://my_site_link_4" target="_blank" class="link3"
                    title="Monday 11/2/2020">
                    Click here for 11/2/2020<br />
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 450px;
  max-width: 1000px; 
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.collapsible_content {
/*
  padding: 0 18px;
*/
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #EEE8AA;
}
```

Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand something but why don't you just run the code ran in your eventlistener's function in the main thread?

In the event where you work with dates later on, you could make a separate function for it, like so:

```
    function collapse_this_week(){
    coll[0].classList.toggle("active");
        var content = coll[0].nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
    }
```

You could pass a parameter to the function to determine which button to expand depending on the date when you start working with dates.

JSFiddle using your code : **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/t1oa4nz0/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for responding Shiverz.  I appreciate the code in JSFiddle.  It runs well.  The button for the first date is expanded and all others are collapsed.  I'm not well versed in JavaScript, but I don't see how the "collapse_this_week" function is called from the 2nd - last button in HTML.  How do I call that function within HTML?  Is it something like: <script>collapse_this_week();</script>?  Would I put that right after the </button> tag?  Also, How would I call the first function (let's say expand_this_week) for a button that's in a location other than the first button?

Comment: Basically, there are a few things happening in this code. Each element that has the "collapsible" class has an Event listener thanks to your for loop. Which means that when you click an element with the collapsible class, it calls the anonymous function that you defined with the Event listener. collapse_this_week() is a separate function, called only once, which expands only the first button. They're two different functions. collapse_this_week is not called with by 2nd button, it's called by the main thread, which is equivalent to ```<script>collapse_this_week();</script>```

Comment: Thanks again.  Got it.  I think the name of the function was tripping me up.  Maybe it should be called "expand_this_week()"?

Comment: Youre right, it should actually, sorry about that that! Haha.. and instead of it taking no arguments you could say that it takes an argument "i", and replace coll[0] by coll[i] so that you can decide which collapsible you want to expand ! With expand_this_week(0), the first one is expanded, and with expand_this_week(1), the second one is expanded, etc...